# 1970s to 1980s book about a man who wakes up in an otherworldly gazebo

Tags: story-identification, books

If I remember correctly, this was not written by a mainstream author. The cover was mostly black-and-white, showing an Asian-style drawing of a garden with the gazebo, some mountains in the distance, etc.. The plot was basically of a man that went to sleep and awoke in this gazebo in another "time/world" and what happened to him there. I sort of remember that there was a spiritual feeling to the story - almost religious - but it's been a long, long time so I could be wrong about that. I feel like he was treated as if he was a god in the "new world" where he woke up.

Comment: What happened to him while he was there?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please add more details to this question - from simple things like what language it was in and whether it was a novel or a short story, to anything you can remember about the plot or what happened in the story. You may be interested in checking out [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) on how to write a good story-ID question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Could you mark [this merged question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122893/1970s-to-1980s-book-about-man-who-wakes-up-in-otherworldly-gazebo) as a duplicate of this one? It's the only question [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+locked%3A1+duplicate%3A0+migrated%3A0) that is a duplicate but isn't marked as one. Compare that to the [23 merged questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+locked%3A1+duplicate%3A1) that are marked as duplicates.

Comment: @amarillo Sure, done. There was some confusion over these two questions because they were posted by the same person with two accounts. First I closed this one as a dupe of the other (since it came second), then I merged the other one with this one (since this one was asked using the registered account), then I reopened this one (but forgot to close the other one as it was already merged), then the accounts were merged.

Comment: @amarillo In retrospect, what I should have done was wait for the accounts to be merged and then merged *this* question with the other one, but now I don't want to try doing that (and risk having both questions merged with each other and neither answerable) since question merges aren't undoable.